# HttpContext.Request the items from listBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

if `HttpContext(context).Request.Params["parameter name"]` can only be used to get the value of the parameter being targeted, how about if I am requesting the items from a listbox?

Let's say, I have `listbox1` full of datas.

Instead of using `foreach (ListItem items in listbox1.items)` how can I make it like `foreach (ListItem items in context.Request.Params["listbox1"].Items)`?

I can't just put it in like that, right?

Is there some way I can request the items of the listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is not possible the way you have mentioned but you can use HiddenField and store the item list with client side scripting and then get the selected list on server side.